# Warning: Attempt to read property "num_rows" on bool in C:\xampp\htdocs\Nice Guys\index.php on line 59

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So, I tried to see if this question had been asked before on here, but none of the questions dealt with non-object errors with a bool error. I'll add the line of code that is causing the error, but please let me know if you need more code for further context, and I will edit the post and add it.

I am basically trying to return search results, and I have a conditional if statement telling the browser to return search results if the results return more rows than 0. I return this error, and I am completely unsure as to why, or what is causing it.

```
    $searchSQL = 'SELECT * FROM images WHERE MATCH (appname, firstname, lastname, image) AGAINST ( "' . 
    $search . '" ) LIMIT ' . $offset . ', 10;';

    $searchResult = $db->query($searchSQL);

    //declade the array variable to store the results
    $output = array();


    if ($searchResult->num_rows > 0)
    {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc() )
        {
            //add row to output array in the form of an associative array 
            $output[] = array ("image" => $row["image"], "firstname" => $row["firstname"], "lastname" => 
            $row["lastname"], "appname" => $row["appname"]);
        }//end while
    }//end if

    $db->close();
```

Comment: Assuming `$db` is a PDO object and the result of the query method returned false? Hence trying to access num_rows on a boolean? [PDO::query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php)

Comment: @Remy - `num_rows` and `fetch_assoc` suggests it's mysqli, but your comment is just as valid for mysqli as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysql\_fetch\_array()/mysql\_fetch\_assoc()/mysql\_fetch\_row()/mysql\_num\_rows etc... expects parameter 1 to be resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-mysql-fetch-assoc-mysql-fetch-row-mysql-num-rows-etc) - Even if the error message is slightly different, it's the exact same problem, as you will see in the accepted answer.

Comment: If the `query` method returned a Boolean type then it’s likely it returned `false` due to failing. There’s an example of getting the error message on https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_error.asp

Comment: Thank you Javier, that did the trick!

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
if ($searchResult !== false && $searchResult->num_rows > 0)
```

This will avoid encountering the missing property on a boolean error in case `mysqli` returns `false`

You could even check that `$searchResult` is not false (or is not boolean) and not worry about the number of rows returned in the `if` clause, since it'll always be false when 0 rows are returned

Comment: The last sentence isn't entirely correct. If the query is valid and just can't match any records, it should still return a mysqli response object, not false. False is returned when the query can't be executed properly, like having invalid syntax, referencing non-existing columns etc.

Comment: This is not the solution to the problem. You are just sweeping the problem under a rug. Enable error reporting to see what is the problem. [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)